# CodeDigger does not generate output

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, pex

I installed the CodeDigger extension to my VS 2013 Premium. Then I enabled the setting to allow it to work with code that is NOT a portable assembly in settings.

After that I right click this simple method to generate the results:

```
public static double Add(double foo, double bar)
{
    return foo + bar;
}
```

But it opens a new tool window and says "listening to monitored x86 process (cold start)" in the status bar, then after a while simply returns nothing, displaying "Ready" in the status bar.

I expect there to be results as shown here: https://rionscode.wordpress.com/2013/04/25/using-pex-and-microsoft-code-digger-to-better-understand-and-test-your-code/

Any ideas why this would not work? All the examples I have seen this kind of thing works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample doesn't have branching or asserts so Pex wont produce anything.

Write a unit test on that code and run pex on your unit test to see more. The pex wiki is also helpful
http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/pex/wiki/How%20Pex%20Will%20Help%20You.html